# How to share the status for FB in Android programatically

Tags: android, facebook

I want to share the text/image programatically from my app on facebook.How should I proceed for that.After lots of googling I found lots of sample apps but as the latest FB SDK is deprecated those APIs it is hard to find the way using new SDK.Please help me out for this issue.

```
 private void publishFeedDialog() {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
         params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
         params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more    installs.");
         params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it     easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
    params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
     params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-     howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (
        new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                FacebookException error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    // When the story is posted, echo the success
                    // and the post Id.
                    final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                    if (postId != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // User clicked the Cancel button
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Publish cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                    // User clicked the "x" button
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Publish cancelled", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Generic, ex: network error
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Error posting story", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        })
        .build();
    feedDialog.show();
}
```

This is what i get for fb API 3.5 doc & which I have tried but it is crashing the app by saying session is null.

Comment: Just display here what have u try? then some one ready to help you brother.

Comment: Try to understand the question before you downvote.

Comment: actually this will open a popup like view and will wait for user to click on either cancel or publish button. Before getting a session, you should open it like: `Session.openActiveSession(Activity activity, boolean AllowLoginUI ,StatusCallback callback);`. Have you done this ?

Comment: sorry brother i never need to any excuse.

Answer (score 0):

Here your session is null because you have not started it yet. 
You have to start your session after login.

You can achieve this by using

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

  // callback when session changes state

});
```

For more information try going through the tutorials from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate/. These are really helpful.

Here is how I implemented --

This class is used to do initial stuffs to facebook

**LoginFacebookClass**

```
/**
* for integrating facebook in your app..
* Firstly import FacebookSDK lib project and add in your project as lib project.
* then 
*  create an instance of this class
* and, then call the facebook login method by passing reference of your activity and   true, if you want to fetch data and, false if you want to share data on faceboko
* Please do whatever you want in the interface callback methods 
* implemented by this class
 * 
 * 
 * Note: Please write a line exactly in your activity's on activity result as
 * -- Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
 * here, 'Session' is Class of Facebook.
 * 'this' is reference of your activity

*/
 public class FacebookLoginClass implements FB_Callback
 {
  Context context;
 FBImPlmentation fbImpl;
String mImageURLString = "", mPhotoTypeString = "";
 // private FBBean userDataBean;

/**
 * constructor for FacebookLoginClass
 * @param con : context of activity
 * @param string 
 * @param mImageURLString2 
 */
public FacebookLoginClass(Context con)
{
    this.context = con;
    fbImpl = FBImPlmentation.getInstance(context, this);
}

public FacebookLoginClass(Context con, String imageURLString, String photoType) 
{
    this.context = con;
    fbImpl = FBImPlmentation.getInstance(context, this);
    mImageURLString = imageURLString;
    mPhotoTypeString = photoType;
}

/**
 * method for initiating facebook Login
 * @param isDataFetch : true for fetching user data, false for sharing on wall
 */
public void facebookLogin(boolean isDataFetch)
{
    fbImpl.CheckSession(isDataFetch);
}

/**
 * method for facebookLogout 
 */
public void facebookLogout()
{
    fbImpl.fbLogout();
}

@Override
public void onLogin(Session s)
{
    fbImpl.getDataFromFB(s);
}

@Override
public void onLoginForShareData()
{
    Log.e("facebook.", "True in..........");
    Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
    postParams.putString("name", "");
    postParams.putString("caption", "");
    postParams.putString("description", " Android, share your pics and videos");
    if (mPhotoTypeString.equalsIgnoreCase("photo")) 
    {
        postParams.putString("picture", mImageURLString);
    } 
    else 
    {
        postParams.putString("link", "");
    }
    fbImpl.publishFeedDialog(postParams);
}

@Override
public void onAuthFailiure()
{

}

@Override
public void onUserData(FBBean fbUserDataBean)
{
    try 
    {
        if (BejoelUtility.isNetworkAvailable(context)) 
        {
            String imageURLString = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + fbUserDataBean.getUserID() + "/picture?type=large";
            new FacebookTwitterLoginAsyncTask(context, fbUserDataBean.getFirstNAme(), fbUserDataBean.getLastName(),
                    fbUserDataBean.getMailId(), fbUserDataBean.getUserBday(), fbUserDataBean.getUserSex(), "", "", imageURLString,
                    fbUserDataBean.getAccessToken(), "facebook").execute();
        } 
        else 
        {
            BejoelUtility.showMsgDialog(context, context.getString(R.string.app_name), context.getString(R.string.no_internet));
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPost(boolean postStatus)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onFriendRequest(boolean shareAppStatus)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onLogout(boolean status)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

**This class interact with facebook**

```
public class FBImPlmentation
{
public static List<String> READ_PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("email");
public List<String> WRITE_PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
private static FBImPlmentation fbImpl;
private FB_Callback mInterface;
private static Activity activity;
boolean isDataFetch=false;
private String mAccessTokenString = "";

/**
 * constructor for facebookImplementation
 * @param con :context of activity via FacebookLogin Class
 * @param mInterface : refrence of class implementing FB_Callback interface..as in our case,
 *  it is refrence of FacebookLogin Class
 * @return : instance of FBImplementation
 */
public static FBImPlmentation getInstance(Context con, FB_Callback mInterface)
{
    activity = (Activity) con;
    if (fbImpl == null)
        fbImpl = new FBImPlmentation();
    fbImpl.mInterface = mInterface;
    return fbImpl;
}

/**
 * method to be called for facebook Logout
 */
public void fbLogout()
{
    if (Session.getActiveSession() != null)
    {
        Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
    Session.setActiveSession(null);
    mInterface.onLogout(true);
}

/**
 * method for checking session.
 * if session is not open, then open a new session.
 * If session is already open then..just call the fbcallback onlogin method
 * @param isDataFetch2 
 */
public void CheckSession(boolean isDataFetch2)
{
    fbImpl.isDataFetch= isDataFetch2;
    Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (s != null && s.isOpened())
    {
        if(isDataFetch)
            mInterface.onLogin(s);
        else
            mInterface.onLoginForShareData();
        mAccessTokenString = s.getAccessToken();
    }
    else
    {
        Session.openActiveSession(activity, true, mFBCallback);
    }
}

//  Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(activity, permissions);
Session.StatusCallback mFBCallback = new Session.StatusCallback()
{
    // call method is always called on session state change
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
    {
        if (session.isOpened())
        {
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!isSubsetOf(READ_PERMISSIONS, permissions))
            {
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(activity, READ_PERMISSIONS);
                session.requestNewReadPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                return;
            }
            else if(isDataFetch)
            {
                mInterface.onLogin(session);
            }
            else
            {
                mInterface.onLoginForShareData();
            }

        }
    }
};

/**
 * method for fetching the user data
 * @param session : it takes the refrence of active session
 */
public void getDataFromFB(Session session)
{
    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback()
    {
        // callback after Graph API response with user object
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                // code to retrieve user's data and pass to signup fragment
                FBBean fbUserDataBean = new FBBean();

                if (mAccessTokenString != null)
                    fbUserDataBean.setAccessToken(mAccessTokenString);
                else 
                {
                    fbUserDataBean.setAccessToken("");
                }

                if (user.getUsername() != null && !(user.getUsername().equals(null)))
                    fbUserDataBean.setUserName(user.getUsername());
                else 
                {
                    fbUserDataBean.setUserName("");
                }

                if (user.getFirstName() != null && !(user.getFirstName().equals(null)))
                    fbUserDataBean.setFirstNAme(user.getFirstName());
                else 
                {
                    fbUserDataBean.setFirstNAme("");
                }

                if (user.getLastName() != null && !(user.getLastName().equals(null)))
                    fbUserDataBean.setLastName(user.getLastName());
                else 
                {
                    fbUserDataBean.setLastName("");
                }

                if (user.getBirthday() != null && !(user.getBirthday().equals(null)))
                    fbUserDataBean.setUserBday(user.getBirthday());
                else 
                {
                    fbUserDataBean.setUserBday("");
                }

                if (user.asMap().get("gender") != null) 
                {
                    fbUserDataBean.setUserSex(user.asMap().get("gender").toString());
                }
                else 
                {
                    fbUserDataBean.setUserSex("");
                }

                if (user.getProperty("email") != null && !(user.getProperty("email").equals(null)))
                    fbUserDataBean.setMailId(user.getProperty("email").toString());
                else 
                {
                    fbUserDataBean.setMailId("");
                }

                if (user.getId() != null && !(user.getId().equals(null)))
                    fbUserDataBean.setUserID(user.getId());
                else 
                {
                    fbUserDataBean.setUserID("");
                }

//        String[] sportsArray = FacebookUtils.getSportsArray(user.getInnerJSONObject());
//                  if (sportsArray != null &&    !(sportsArray.equals(null)))
  //                        fbUserDataBean.setSportsname(sportsArray);

                mInterface.onUserData(fbUserDataBean);
             }
        }
    });
}

private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset)
{
    for (String string : subset)
    {
        if (!superset.contains(string))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * method for publishing posts
 */
public void publishFeedDialog(Bundle postParams)
{
    Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
    List<String> permissions = s.getPermissions();
    if (!isSubsetOf(WRITE_PERMISSIONS, permissions))
    {
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(activity,
                WRITE_PERMISSIONS);
        s.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
        return;
    }

 //     Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
//      postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
//      postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more    installs.");
//      postParams.putString("description", "Video by Lata manadjahgkfdjhaskjd akhgfkjashfkjash");
   //       postParams.putString("link", "");
    //        postParams.putString("picture", "");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(activity, Session.getActiveSession(), postParams))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error)
                {
                    if (error == null)
                    {
                        // When the story is posted, echo the success
                        // and the post Id.
                        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                        if (postId != null)
                        {
                            mInterface.onPost(true);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // User clicked the Cancel button
                            mInterface.onPost(false);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException)
                        {
                            // User clicked the "x" button
                            //                              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "Publish cancelled",
                            //                                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mInterface.onPost(false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Generic, ex: network error
                            //                              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), "Error posting story",
                            //                                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mInterface.onAuthFailiure();
                        }
                }

            }).build();
    feedDialog.show();
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.It works like a charm...I am able to launch facebook login page but what is my main aim is to also share/post image/data once login get successfull.I have gone through the link you had given for next help but unable to understand the things.If you have the code for my requirement can you please share it?Thanks in advance